# OneToOne and JoinTable

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, one-to-one

I am trying to associate a JPA Enity *Site* to another JPA Entity (*Address*) with a unidirectional one-to-one relation, but I cannot get it to work. 
A complication is that the entity owning the relationship (Site) is abstract, and it is implemented by another entity, namely *Museum*.
A further complication is that the abstract entity inherits from a third entity, still abstract, namely IdentifiableEntity.

Here is the code:

**Site:**

```
@Configurable
@Entity
public abstract class Site extends IdentifiableEntity {

@NotNull
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "address_id")
private Address address;

public Address getAddress() {
    return this.address;
}

public void setAddress(Address address) {
    this.address = address;
}
}
```

**Address:**

```
@Configurable
@Entity
public class Address extends IdentifiableEntity {

@NotNull
private String street;

private String number;
}
```

**Museum:**

```
@Configurable
@Entity
public class Museum extends Site {
    /* some stuff */
}
```

For each entity, I created a JPARepository.

During deploy, no errors appear to exist, but when trying to access the database by invoking a findAll on the SiteRepository (i.e. the interface extending JPARepository), I get the following runtime error stack:

```
HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; 
nested exception is org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: 
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: 
    could not extract ResultSet; 
    nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: 
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet

root cause:
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'site0_.address' in 'field list'
```

Comment: Do you have setters and getters in Address Class ?  if not add them.

Comment: Added them and got a new error, which is now in the post, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try defining the join column for the @OneToOne relationship, e.g.:

```
@OneToOne @JoinColumn(name="address_id")
private Address address;
```

If you don't explicitly define the join column, it defaults to the name of the variable, and I think that's why you get the message `Unknown column 'site0_.address'`.

Of course also make sure that the join column exists in the table (unless you use `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update`).

Comment: What is the name of the join column in the database table?

Comment: the column name is museum.address and the error is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set com.lh.clte.domain.Address field com.lh.clte.domain.Site.address to com.lh.clte.domain.Museum

Comment: This is a different error, can you show the code where this error occurs?

Comment: the address field the error is referring to is part of Site, so the code is already in the main post. I updated the post to include the JoinColumn annotation.

Comment: OK, I have some news: with your advice, if I manually populate the database for testing purpose, it doesn't work. If I save an instance via repository, it does. Given I am inserting exactly the same database entries, what's the matter with manually populating the db?

Comment: It could be caused by Hibernate's cache. Did you restart the java process after manually inserting?

Comment: yes, but I also have a table named hibernate_sequences I did not create. I don't populate it when I manually insert entires

Comment: Hmm, this could be why, but I couldn't explain it.